# No longer an absolute beginner, unsure of diet

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, beginners, bmi, cutting

I follow reddit's bodyweight fitness and have been doing it on and off for a few years. However, it was only this year that I have been seriously doing it with only a couple months of break this summer due to injury.

Now I am noticeably stronger than before. I have moved most of my exercises to rings and I've gained considerable weight. Just as a reference of my current level, I now do 3 sets of ring pushups at low reps(5-8). I'm 6' and 175lb and from appearance I may be around 24% bmi

I still feel pretty good progression on my workout and feel confident that I can gain more mass as long as I eat well. However, I am getting slightly put off by the extra fat. Is this time for me to cut? Am I still considered a beginner in the sense that I can lose fat and gain muscle at a TDEE deficit?

As for diet I'm not calorie counting but I have been taking effort to maximize my protein intake. I also have a good feel of how much food I am eating and can generally control my calorie intake +/-500 relatively ok.

My goal isn't to be extremely buff but be fit and lean but not skinny. I think 15% bmi is my ultimate goal, just have some ab definition.

Comment: Where does this notion of "only beginners can put on muscle and lose fat at the same time" come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no correct answer, its entirely down to you. Do you want to look 'ripped'? If so, cut.

If you want to continue to progress then continue your eating at a slight bulk or look at leangains/clean bulking.

Based on your goals I would say you should start a cut, when you can see your muscles more then consider if you should continue to a low bodyfat percentage or bulk back up and build more muscle.